# Find Directory and copy another directory to found directory?

Tags: bash, shell, find, file-copy

I'm attempting to find a directory A that could be in a variable location and copy another directory B into the found directory. So, I'd like to find directory `A`, and copy Directory B into Directory A.

```
find -name "foo.bundle"; cp directory B into the found directory.
```

If there are multiple matching A directories, I want to copy B to each of them.

Comment: Move or copy? There's a difference...

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge for help with your accounts.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /search/tree/root -type d -name "foo.bundle" -exec cp -Rp /path/to/B {} \;
```

**Edit 1**

Some explanation has been requested...

1. `-type d` limits the search results to directories
2. `-exec ... ;` executes the command; `{}` is replaced by the path of the current match; `";"` is required by find and it has to be quoted for the shell.

Comment: The guy who asked this probably isn't a shell expert, so it might be helpful if you provided some explanation for his learning. If you do, +1.